# How do I delete cookies set by sub domain in the parent domain?

Tags: angularjs, cookies, angular-cookies

I have situation where I need to set a cookie(`token`) from sub domain(`account.test.com`). So I implemented it using angular-cookies. Now under browser cookies, I see `token` is to value `xyz`, path to `/` and domain to `.test.com`.

In `test.com` also I set a cookie(`orId`) to value `pqrs`, path to `/` and domain to `test.com`. In `test.com` dev tools I see cookies set from `account.test.com` and where I'm able to read `token` which is completely fine.

Now I have a usecase to delete `token` and `orId` from `test.com`. I tried using angular-cookies `$cookie.remove('token')` and `$cookie.remove('orId')`. I see only `orId` is deleted but not `token`. So how to delete `token` set by `account.test.com` from the parent domain `test.com`.